# Need Java Code/Logic to extract COMP. field from EBCDIC file

Tags: java, cobol, copybook

Need java code or logic to unpack COBOL COMP. field from EBCDIC file. Please help

I have tried the below code for unpacking comp. But some value i getting is in negative. Ex. 8188  we are getting  as -57348

```
public static String getBinary(byte[] b,int decimalPointLocation) {
    long val = 0;
    int first_byte = b[0] & 0x0F;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        int low = b[i] & 0x0F;
        int high = (b[i] >> 4) & 0x0f;
        if (low < 0)
            low *= -1;
        if (high < 0)
            high *= -1;
        if(first_byte==15){
            high = 15 -high;
            low = 15 - low;
        }
        int num = high * 16 + low;
        val = 256 * val + num;
    }
    if(first_byte == 15){
        val++;
    }
    String s = ""+val;
    while(s.length()<b.length*2){
        s="0"+s;
    }
    if(first_byte == 15){
        s="-"+s;
    }
    if (decimalPointLocation > 0) {
        s = s.substring(0,
                (s.length() - decimalPointLocation))
                + "."
                + s.substring(s.length()
                        - decimalPointLocation);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This is not do my homework site. Kindly read Help Center to know how to ask questions here so that you will get answers not question ban!

Comment: Sorry. I added already tried code which was not working properly.

Comment: You might consider to delete your question nonetheless. Then read [mcve] and then write up a new better question. Those -10 might most likely stick, and prevent people from even looking at your question. Although, up to -7 already.

Comment: @Lino More people than you think. There are still mainframes on this planet, they are still running tons and tons of cobol code, and without that, our world would look very much different.

Comment: You don't "unpack" a COBOL **COMP** variable.  You can unpack a COBOL **COMP-3** variable.  COMP is analogous to primitive data type int in Java.  COMP-3 is packed [BCD (Binary Coded Decimal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#Packed_BCD).  Which is it?

Comment: You mention the file is EBCDIC, is your Java code running on a mainframe -or- have you downloaded a mainframe file ensuring there is no code page conversion as part of your download process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not use Java, but I will try to explain what is happening.

The value `8188` is `0x1ff8` in big-endian hex. When your program is run the result is actually `8188 - 65536 = -57348`. That is why you got the result you did.

Because the input is big-endian binary, only the first bit of `b[0]` should be checked for a sign. What I did in C# was,

```
    public static String GetBinary(byte[] b, int decimalPointLocation)
    {
        long val = 0;
        if ((b[0] & 0x80) != 0)
        {
            val = -1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
                val = (val << 8) + b[i];
        }
        string s = Convert.ToString(val);
        return s;
    }
```

For `byte[] b = {0x1f, 0xfc}` the value returned is `8188`. For `byte[] b = {0xe0, 0x04}` the value returned is `-8188`.

While I did use similar substring manipulation to insert a decimal point for those values, you need to be aware that absolute integer values less than 100 cannot be properly formatted for two decimal places with that method.